# Firebase realtime database and angular/ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I need some help for queries on firebase realtime database.

How I get all data on the database of the specific customerID for example getting all purchase product of the user who logged in on the system on realtime database firebase on angular and all the data will push on a array to display it into the view

This is my sample code:

[image]

I already get the data, but I have a problem to display it will always duplicating my record but not on the database only on the view I don't think this is the proper way the beekeeperID is the id of the user who loggedin, thanks

// this is the code on page.ts file

```
 beekeeperData: any[] = [];
  beekeeperRef: AngularFireList<any>;
  beekeeperUser: Product;
  productData: any[] = [];

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, private shared: SharedService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    
     this.beekeeperUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
     let beekeeperID = this.beekeeperUser.uid;

     console.log(beekeeperID);

    // not finish debug duplicate record
    this.shared.getProduct().subscribe(list => {
    
      list.map(item => {
        this.beekeeperData.push({id: item.key, ...item.payload.val()}); 
        this.beekeeperData.filter(product => {
          if(product.beekeeperId === beekeeperID) {
             this.productData.push(product);
          }
        })
     
      })
    }) 

  } // end of oninit

// this is the code on the service file
getProduct = () => {
    this.productDetailsList = this.firebase.list('productDetails');
    return this.productDetailsList.snapshotChanges();
  }
```

Comment: this.shared.getProduct().subscribe(list => {
    
      list.map(item => {
        this.beekeeperData.push(item.payload.val()); 
        this.beekeeperData.filter(product => {
          if(product.beekeeperId === beekeeperID) {
             this.productData.push({id:item.key, ...product});
          }
        })
         console.log(this.productData)
      })
    }) 

  } // this is the code on the image

Comment: getProduct = () => {
    this.productDetailsList = this.firebase.list('productDetails');
    return this.productDetailsList.snapshotChanges();
  } // this is the getProduct function on the service